# Istio | Envoy Proxy Problem: 0 NR filter_chain_not_found | TCP - Python Socket Client and Socket Server in one cluster (MESH_INTERNAL)

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, mtls, servicemesh

i have a minor problem with Istio and the EnvoyProxy: **NR filter_chain_not_found**

The socket client and the socket server run within the same cluster (seperated docker-container) and send each other plaintext messages at intervals. The socket server runs on port 50000, the socket client on port 50001. Without mTLS (PERMISSIVE), the communication works without problems. If I activate mTLS (STRICT), the error listed below occurs. I have already tried writing EnvoyFilters, but I can't imagine that this is the right way.

## Log from the envoy-proxy:

**On the Socket Server side:**

`[2023-01-16T19:52:55.941Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 5000 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 10.1.2.142:50000 10.1.2.146:50001 - -`

`[2023-01-16T19:58:05.909Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 5001 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 10.1.2.142:50000 10.1.2.146:50001 - -`

**On the Socket Client side:**

```
Connect to SocketServer...  server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
SERVER_NAME as string => server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/service/server-c-socket-client.py", line 94, in <module>
main()
File "/service/server-c-socket-client.py", line 91, in main
ConnectToSocketServer(SERVER_NAME)
File "/service/server-c-socket-client.py", line 60, in ConnectToSocketServer
answer = con.recv(1024)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

## Some More Informations:

**istio-strict-meshpolicy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
kind: PeerAuthentication
 metadata:
   name: "default"
   namespace: "istio-system"
 spec:
   mtls:
     mode: STRICT
```

**istio-virtualservice-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-client-virtualservice
  namespace: server-c-socket-client
spec:
  hosts:
  - server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 50001
    route:
    - destination:
      host: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 50001
    weight: 100
```

**istio-virtualservice-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-server-virtualservice
  namespace: server-c-socket-server
spec:
  hosts: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
  tcp:
  route:
  - destination:
    host: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
    port:
      number: 50000
  weight: 100
```

**istio-destinationrule-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 
kind: DestinationRule 
metadata:
   name: server-c-socket-client-destinationrule
   namespace: server-c-socket-client 
spec:
   host: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
   trafficPolicy:
     tls:
       mode: MUTUAL
       credentialName: cacerts
       sni: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
```

**istio-destinationrule-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule 
metadata:
   name: server-c-socket-server-destinationrule
   namespace: server-c-socket-server
 spec:
   host: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
   trafficPolicy:
     tls:
       mode: MUTUAL
       credentialName: cacerts
       sni: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
```

**istio-peerauthentication-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
kind: PeerAuthentication 
metadata:
   name: server-c-socket-client-peerauthentication
   namespace: server-c-socket-client
 spec:
   mtls:
     mode: STRICT
```

**istio-peerauthentication-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
   name: server-c-socket-server-peerauthentication
   namespace: server-c-socket-server
 spec:
   mtls:
     mode: STRICT
```

## System

**Kubernetes:** MicroK8s v1.25.5 revision 4418

**kubectl version:**
Client Version: v1.25.5
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.25.5

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.1

**istioctl proxy-status**

```
NAME                                                                      CLUSTER        CDS        LDS        EDS        RDS          ECDS         ISTIOD                     VERSION
istio-ingressgateway-78f69b5b89-w24fx.istio-system                        Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     NOT SENT     NOT SENT     istiod-d887c9b84-xk9tn     1.14.4
server-c-nginx-deploy-7cb9cc7574-57tdw.server-c-nginx                     Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-d887c9b84-xk9tn     1.14.4
server-c-socket-client-deploy-7469697f89-ndf89.server-c-socket-client     Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-d887c9b84-xk9tn     1.14.4
server-c-socket-server-deploy-5d47669d86-fk8kh.server-c-socket-server     Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-d887c9b84-xk9tn     1.14.4
```

I have already tried many properties in istio and have struggled with creating an EnvoyFilter, which unfortunately does not give the desired results.
As an example: "NR filter_chain_not_found" #30819 https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/30819 or https://vikaschoudhary16.com/2022/06/20/undeistio-permissive-authz-magic/#Scenario_2_non-injected_client_to_injected_and_non-injected_services

In the end, the plain text messages (TCP) should be encrypted, which does not work in STRICT mode.

If you have any ideas or need more information, please let me know.

Best regards.

---

## Some Updated files | 01/19/2023:

- the communication is in one cluster
- no outgoing / ingoing external clustertraffic (eg. no ingress or egress gateway is configured)
- the Socket Server is in the namespace: server-c-socket-server
- the Socket Client is in the namespace: server-c-socket-client
- if i edit the PeerAuthentication from the Socket Server to PERMISSIVE its works immediately, but not encrypted... :(
- I also added a sleep command to the socket client Python script (about 3 minutes), as I suspected a timing problem between deployment and envoy-sidecar
- What I noticed with the error with the Envoy "10.1.2.142:50000 10.1.2.146:50001" the first IP-address is the Socket Server and the second one is the Socket Client, its looks like the Server does not know how to reply the Socket-connection request...

**istio-destinationrule-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-client-destinationrule
  namespace: server-c-socket-client
spec:
  host: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
      sni: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
```

**istio-destinationrule-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-server-destinationrule
  namespace: server-c-socket-server
spec:
  host: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
      sni: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
```

**istio-peerauthentication-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-server-peerauthentication
  namespace: server-c-socket-server
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

**istio-peerauthentication-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-client-peerauthentication
  namespace: server-c-socket-client
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

**istio-strict-meshpolicy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

**istio-virtualservice-socket-client.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-client-virtualservice
  namespace: server-c-socket-client
spec:
  hosts:
  - server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 50001
    route:
    - destination:
        host: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 50001
      weight: 100
```

**istio-virtualservice-socket-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-c-socket-server-virtualservice
  namespace: server-c-socket-server
spec:
  hosts:
  - server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 50000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 50000
      weight: 100
```

**istio-protocolversion.yaml**

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    enableTracing: true
    accessLogFile: "/dev/stdout"
    meshMTLS:
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
```

```
server-c@server-c:~$ microk8s istioctl experimental describe pod server-c-socket-client-deploy-7469697f89-ngktr.server-c-socket-client
Pod: server-c-socket-client-deploy-7469697f89-ngktr.server-c-socket-client
   Pod Revision: default
   Pod Ports: 50001 (server-c-socket-client-app), 15090 (istio-proxy)
   WARNING: User ID (UID) 1337 is reserved for the sidecar proxy.
--------------------
Service: server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client
   Port: tcp 50001/TCP targets pod port 50001
DestinationRule: server-c-socket-client-destinationrule.server-c-socket-client for "server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local"
   Matching subsets: v1
   Traffic Policy TLS Mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
--------------------
Effective PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS mode: STRICT
Applied PeerAuthentication:
   default.istio-system, server-c-socket-client-peerauthentication.server-c-socket-client
```

```
server-c@server-c:~$ microk8s istioctl experimental describe pod server-c-socket-server-deploy-5d47669d86-s9wzj.server-c-socket-server
Pod: server-c-socket-server-deploy-5d47669d86-s9wzj.server-c-socket-server
   Pod Revision: default
   Pod Ports: 50000 (server-c-socket-server-app), 15090 (istio-proxy)
   WARNING: User ID (UID) 1337 is reserved for the sidecar proxy.
--------------------
Service: server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server
   Port: tcp 50000/TCP targets pod port 50000
DestinationRule: server-c-socket-server-destinationrule.server-c-socket-server for "server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local"
   Matching subsets: v1
   Traffic Policy TLS Mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
--------------------
Effective PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS mode: STRICT
Applied PeerAuthentication:
   default.istio-system, server-c-socket-server-peerauthentication.server-c-socket-server
```

**mtls: STRICT**

```
server-c@server-c:~$ microk8s istioctl pc listeners deploy/server-c-socket-server-deploy -n server-c-socket-server --port 15006
ADDRESS         PORT    MATCH                                                                                       DESTINATION
0.0.0.0         15006   Addr: *:15006                                                                               Non-HTTP/Non-TCP
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; App: istio-http/1.0,istio-http/1.1,istio-h2; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                    InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                                                 InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; Addr: *:50000                                                                   Cluster: inbound|50000||
```

**mtls: PERMISSIVE**

```
server-c@server-c:~$ microk8s istioctl pc listeners deploy/server-c-socket-server-deploy -n server-c-socket-server --port 15006
ADDRESS         PORT  MATCH                                                                                                         DESTINATION
0.0.0.0         15006   Addr: *:15006                                                                                               Non-HTTP/Non-TCP
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; App: istio-http/1.0,istio-http/1.1,istio-h2; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                    InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: raw_buffer; App: http/1.1,h2c; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                                       InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; App: TCP TLS; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                                                   InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: raw_buffer; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                                                          InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; Addr: 0.0.0.0/0                                                                                 InboundPassthroughClusterIpv4
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; App: istio,istio-peer-exchange,istio-http/1.0,istio-http/1.1,istio-h2; Addr: *:50000            Cluster: inbound|50000||
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; Addr: *:50000                                                                                   Cluster: inbound|50000||
0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: raw_buffer; Addr: *:50000                                                                            Cluster: inbound|50000||
```

Comment: In destination rule tls mode is mentioned as "MUTUAL".  whether the client / server certificates are loaded respectively.  In server namespace virtual service destination is defined without any match rule for ex: match port of server.  can you please more details of traffic routing, client pod in one namespace is directly reaching to server pod in another namespace.

Comment: Hey, i have updated the "istio-virtualservice-socket-server.yaml": 

` 
...
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 50000
    route:
    - destination:
...
` 

I also have created with Makefile.selfsigned.mk from istio a new root-ca, two certificates for each namespace and updated both DestinationRules: 

` 
server-c-socket-server   caservercerts                         Opaque                                4      8m10s
server-c-socket-client   caclientcerts                         Opaque                                4      7m37s
`

Comment: Small Update, i just fixed the DestinationRule, but still got the same problem:

DestinationRule: server-c-socket-server-destinationrule.server-c-socket-server for "server-c-socket-server-service.server-c-socket-server.svc.cluster.local"

DestinationRule: server-c-socket-client-destinationrule.server-c-socket-client for "server-c-socket-client-service.server-c-socket-client.svc.cluster.local"

I m not sure, what kind of traffic routing-information you expect, maybe u can give me a hint...

Best regards

Comment: when i mean traffic routing, the secure communication is being setup is from pod to pod or external traffic reaching to pod.  because client is one namespace and server is other namespace.  you need to check the gateway configuration as well.  simple would be use mode "ISTIO_MUTUAL" instead of MUTUAL where istio will maintain secure communication.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The two namespaces are in the same cluster and only communicate within it. I do not have ingress or egress traffic and therefore have not set up a gateway for these types. I will switch from MUTUAL to ISTIO_MUTUAL later and test this.

Comment: I have made the change to ISTIO_MUTUAL, but unfortunately this has done nothing.

I have supplemented the post with the adapted files and further information. I would be really happy if I could get this communication between the two services encrypted.

Comment: In the shared proxy config log of server when mTLS is enabled as Strict its showing the TLS is enabled for the server.  and also no other entries or configuration where plain text is enabled.  similarly if you take dump of proxy config for client you would notice tls configuration.  following log entry  "0.0.0.0         15006   Trans: tls; Addr: *:50000                                                                   Cluster: inbound|50000||" confirms that it configured with TLS.   so communication between pods is in mTLS mode not in plain text.

Comment: Unfortunately, the communication does not work when I set the peer authentication for the socket server to STRICT. The Envoy proxy then throws the "filter_chain_not_found" error message. If I set the server to PERMISSIVE I can see via the tool Ksniff that the communication is encrypted, except for the TCP socket transmission...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so focused on Istio that I didn’t look further at the underlying application…

In my previous application, the server was trying to communicate directly with the client pod and not via the socket client service (which was the basic problem). I have changed my application so that there is a socket client and a socket server on both sides. These are spawned alternately, so that first client A contacts server B and then client B contacts server A => always alternating. This means that I can now track the connectivity of the two services in Istio and subsequently try them with mTLS. [Working Socket Client and Server => mTLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9vvE.jpg)